# What is a Timer Event in Python?

Tags: python, events, timer

I've been enrolled in a **python** course and in today's lecture the instructor taught us about event driven programming. Now I came across input events, keyboard events etc, but I couldn't understand what a ***timer event*** is and what role it plays.

Answer (score 0):

A "timer" event occurs either (A) once, after a specific amount of time has passed, or (B) every X milliseconds/seconds/minutes.

For example, consider a computer game. When you press joypad buttons to move the player character around, you're sending **input** events to the program. A simple turn-based game might be coded to re-draw the game world whenever the user presses something, since that's the only time that anything on-screen would need to change.

For a platform game, though, AI-controlled characters would need to be able to move around the screen, even when the player isn't pressing anything. In this case, you could set up a **timer** event that updates the state of enemy monsters every 20 milliseconds.

It's worth noting that timer events aren't specific to Python - for example, [GLUT](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node64.html) and [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers) both provide time-based callback functionality.